# Dynamically allocating array of structures c programming

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Hi so im trying to use calloc to allocate an array of pointers to structs as shown below but in the line where I try to assign one of the pointers in the array to a struct Which was also dynamically allocated, I'm having trouble.

```
struct node
{
    int c;
};
typedef struct node Node;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int **ptrArr;
    int intArr[NUM] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Node *ptr;

    *ptrArr = calloc (NUM, sizeof(Node *));
    for (i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
        ptrArr[i] = calloc (NUM, sizeof(Node *));
    }

    for (i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
        ptr = calloc (1, sizeof(Node));
        (*ptr).c = intArr[i];
        ptrArr[i] = ptr;  /*line with the compiler issue*/    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int **ptrArr;` --> `Node **ptrArr;`, `calloc (NUM, sizeof(Node *))` --> `calloc (NUM, sizeof(Node))` (in this case occurs memory leak.)

Comment: `*ptrArr = calloc (NUM, sizeof(Node *));` ==> `ptrArr = calloc (NUM, sizeof(Node *));`

Comment: You dereference ptrArr without initializing it first, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ptrArr` needs to be type `Node **`, not `int **`:

```
Node **ptrArr = NULL;
```

Then the actual allocations would be:

```
ptrArr = calloc( NUM, sizeof *ptrArr );
if ( ptrArr )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < NUM; i++ )
    ptrArr[i] = malloc( sizeof *ptrArr[i] );
}
```

Since the type of `ptrArr` is `Node **`, then the type of `*ptrArr` is `Node *`, so `sizeof *ptrArr` is equivalent to `sizeof (Node *)`, and `sizeof *ptrArr[i]` is equivalent to `sizeof (Node)`.  In general,

```
T *p = calloc( NUM, sizeof *p );
```

or

```
T *p = malloc( NUM * sizeof *p );
```

will always do the right thing for any type `T`.

**Edit**

You're creating a memory leak - you allocate memory for each `ptrArr[i]`, then later on you allocate memory for `ptr` and *overwrite* the previous value of `ptrArr[i]`, losing your reference to the memory that was allocated earlier.  You don't need to create the separate `ptr` object; just write

```
ptrArr[i]->c = intArr[i];
```